# Dell U2722D & U2722DE + lenovo laptips

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad, displayport, daisychaining, usb-3.1-type-c

I work in a small company, lately my boss bought serval couples of Dell U2722D & U2722DE

The set up is we connect to the DE panel with type c and from there dp daisy chain to the D channel, this works perfectly on my hp spectre 14 and on a Dell latitude 5420 of a coworkers both 11th gen i7, on the other hand we got co-workers with thinkpad x1 carbon (10th gen i7) and thinkpad P14 (11th gen i7) both do not allow the full resulution for the daisy chained screen (the D variant). On the P14 it allows up to 1920x1080 & on the x1 it allows a bit higher resolution.

On a docking station you can connect both lenovo's and get full resolution.
Needless to say both screens are quad HD.

I'm asking because we want to make these displays our standard and we have 2 packaged x1 carbon (11th gen i7) for future employees

. What should we do about this? Is there something we can do on the problematic laptops to fix this? Should we return the x1's we didn't open?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Can it be fixed?